# Leaftlet Marker events from mobile device

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mobile-browser

I have a leaflet server running with markers, and dragging the markers successfully fires the `dragend` event upon completion. I've used this extensively from the desktop browser (chrome).

However, upon accessing the server from the chrome mobile app (Pixel), the markers don't fire any events when dragging is completed. Note however that everything else on mobile looks and functions great. The map looks good, I can zoom in/out, and I can drag the markers very smoothly.

Here's an example of how I'm handling `dragend` events:

```
marker.on('dragend', (event) => {
    const position = marker.getLatLng();
    alert(position);
});
```

Note that in case the `alert` is the problem, this isn't what interests me, as I'm monitoring the server log and the `dragend` event is not being triggered at all.

I've found one similar question pertaining to angular; I am not using angular so I did not find it very helpful.

Thank you.